# Requested output 'm4a' is not a suitable output format

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I am attempting to combine `youtube-dl` and `ffmpeg` to clip audio from YouTube videos. Everything was fine on my laptop, but when I moved to my server (Debian 9) I started coming across this error. Why is this? Am I missing a dependency ... if so which one?

**Input**

```
ffmpeg -f m4a $(youtube-dl -f bestaudio[ext=m4a] -g \'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnjYyfkcaNI\' | sed "s/.*/-ss 0 -i &/") -to 60 -c copy -y /public/audio/test.m4a
```

**Error**

> [NULL @ 0x55cf161f1e60] Requested output format 'm4a' is not a
>   suitable output format /public/audio/test.m4a: Invalid argument

**ffmpeg info**

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.12-1~deb9u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was not with `ffmpeg`. The `youtube-dl` command was failing and resulting in the error.

**Updated command**

```
ffmpeg -f m4a $(youtube-dl -f bestaudio[ext=m4a] -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnjYyfkcaNI | sed "s/.*/-ss 0 -i &/") -to 60 -c copy -y /public/audio/test.m4a
```

Basically just had to remove the `\'`.

I also had to go one step further and give permission to the `www-data` apache group for the output folder since the command was being executed from a PHP script.